# Working on an external dataset

Tags: python, dataset, scikit-learn

I'm quite new to scikit-learn and was going through some of the examples of learning and predicting the samples in the iris dataset. But how do I load an external dataset for this purpose?

I downloaded a dataset that has data in the following form;

```
id attr1 attr2 .... label
123 0 0 ..... abc
234 0 0 ..... dsf
....
....
```

So how should I load this dataset in order to learn and draw prediction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/). Assuming the data is space separated:

```
import pandas as pd
X = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=' ').values
```

where [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) returns a `DataFrame`, and the `values` attribute returns a numpy array containing the data. You might want to separate out the last column of the above `X` as the labels, say into a one dimensional array `y`:

```
X, y = X[:, :-1], X[:, -1]
```

Comment: I'm quite familiar with numpy, so I used the same technique for seperating the labels. Thanks.